# Twitter Bootstrap - Polaroid effect (CSS) shifts grid

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am building a page using Twitter Bootstrap. To display an image gallery, I use a setup like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span1">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="http://www.placehold.it/50x50" />
            </a>
        </div><!-- /.span -->
        <div class="span1">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="http://www.placehold.it/50x50" />
            </a>
        </div><!-- /.span -->
        <div class="span1">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="http://www.placehold.it/50x50" />
            </a>
        </div><!-- /.span -->
    </div><!-- /.row -->
</div><!-- /.container -->
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UFxsP/1/)

Now I want some kind of polaroid effect on these image. To do this, I add a class `photo` which holds the `a` and `img`. Like this:

```
<div class="span1">
    <div class="photo">
        <a href="#">
            <img src="http://www.placehold.it/50x50" />
        </a>
    </div>
</div><!-- /.span -->
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UFxsP/)

As you can see, adding this class shifts the grid somehow. That's why the grid is not centered anymore. Is there anything I can do to fix this?

The best would be if the `span` gets a `background-color` and the image sits centered in the `span`. I believe using padding I then can control the width of the border - this is the initial idea, but it's not working. How would you create an effect like this. Using a `border-iage` also shifts the grid.

I added some screenshots:

Here the first example - visually centered
[image: Example 1]

And the second example - clearly shifted
[image: Example 2]

Comment: Both of those look the same to me, except for the red background bleeding in the second one. Could you make screenshots and point out the difference you mean?

Comment: @millimoose added screenshots. You see, the margin from the left side to the red box (image 2) is the same as the margin from the left side to the image. But on the right side, it's not the same - the thumbnails are shifted to the right.

Comment: Those aren't screenshots of the fiddles you linked though. Anyway, since you made it work there isn't much point in fixing it anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem. Forgot that I had added `width` and `height` to `.photo`. After removing these values, it's working like it should.